# How to cancel a browse dialog in AIR for Android?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air

I have an app here allowing the user to upload images. To pick the image I open the native browser with
`var file:File = new File;
file.browse();`

I encounter a strange problem when the user cancels the upload. In fact there are two ways this can be done:

a) the user clicks on the "back" button on the device or:

b) user clicks on an empty space on the (native) browse dialog window.

In the first case, AIR will fire an Event.CANCEL event and everything is fine.

In the second case no event will fire, still the browse dialog will quit, leaving my app in the state of still waiting for an upload. To deal with this, I added another button to my UI that will fire the event and call `file.cancel(); file = null` manually.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected. When I try to open the browse dialog again, I get an Error `Error #2041: Only one file browsing session may be performed at a time`. The cancel is ignored.

Does anybody have an idea how to workaround this problem?

P.S. Tested on AIR 13 and Android 4.1 / Android 4.3